# Jquery :not()selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
#thisdiv {padding:10px; margin:-15px 0 0 40px; background-color:#333; position:absolute; display:none;}
div.block {margin-top:10px; width:200px;}
div#thisdiv a {color:#fff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id ="one" class="block"><a href="">one</a></div>
 <div id="thisdiv">hello</div>
<div id ="two"class="block">two</div>
<div id ="three"class="block">three/div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one').hover(function() {
   $('#thisdiv').fadeIn(400);
  }); 

  $('div:not(#thisdiv)').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#thisdiv').fadeOut(400) 
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`#thisdiv` doesn't fadeOut. I could have used the following, but it only fades out if the cursor mouse outs of #thisdiv. Is there any way i can solve this so when the cursor navigates away from anyway, the div still fade out.

```
$('#thisdiv').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#thisdiv').fadeOut(400) 
  });
```

I couldn't figure out what's why jquery's :not selector is not doing what I wanted to.
Am i using it wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

1 - You need to use `mouseover`, not `hover` for the first binding:

```
  $('#one').mouseover(function() {
     $('#thisdiv').fadeIn(400);
  });
```

`hover` accepts two function parameters (mouseover/mouseout).

2 - Your closing div tag at the end of your markup is broken (missing a `<`):

```
<div id ="three"class="block">three/div> <-- here
```

I tested your code having made the above modifications, and it seems to work as you want it to (if I've understood correctly). Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CwjB5/1/).

Comment: sorry about the broken markup, i had to delete away a href tags because stackoverflow don't allow me to have more than 1 a href in a post.
Your link example works fine, but i guess i did not make it clear tho. #thisdiv only disappears when i have to move my cursor to the div and mouse out.

when i mouse over #one, #thisdiv appears, but when i move to #two, #thisdiv still stays there. This is the problem and at the same time, #thisdiv is a div that has a link for user to click.

I could only though of using :not selector so when i mouseout to anywhere except #thisdiv, #thisdiv will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to explicitly set the time, you will need to pass it in as a hash parameter. Otherwise you can use 'slow', 'fast' or the default which is 400.

```
$('#my_button').mouseleave(function(){ $(this).fadeOut({duration:1000}) })
```